# Is it possible to add distinct to part of a sum clause in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, plsql

I have a pretty lengthy SQL query which I'm going to run on Oracle via hibernate. It consists of two nested selects. In the first select statement, a number of sums are calculated, but in one of them I want to filter the results using unique ids.

```
SELECT ...
SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN SECOND_STATUS= 50 OR SECOND_STATUS IS NULL THEN RECEIVE_AMOUNT END, 0) + 
NVL(CASE WHEN FIRST_STATUS = 1010 THEN AMOUNT END, 0) + 
NVL(CASE WHEN FIRST_STATUS = 1030 THEN AMOUNT END, 0) - 
NVL(CASE WHEN FIRST_STATUS = 1010 AND (SECOND_STATUS= 50 OR SECOND_STATUS IS NULL) THEN RECEIVE_AMOUNT END, 0)) TOTAL, ...
```

And at the end:

```
... FROM (SELECT s.*, p.* FROM FIRST_TABLE s
JOIN SECOND_TABLE p ON s.ID = p.FIRST_ID
```

In one of the lines that start with NVL (second line actually), I want to add a distinct clause that sums the amounts only if first table ids are unique. But I don't know if this is possible or not. If yes, how would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume such setup

```
select * from first;

        ID     AMOUNT
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         20
         
select * from second; 

 SECOND_ID   FIRST_ID    AMOUNT2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        100
         2          1        100
         3          2        100
```

After the join you get the total sum of both amounts too high because the amount from the first table is duplicated.

```
select * 
from first
join second on first.id = second.first_id;

        ID     AMOUNT  SECOND_ID   FIRST_ID    AMOUNT2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10          1          1        100
         1         10          2          1        100
         2         20          3          2        100
```

You must add a `row_number` that identifies the first occurence in the parent table and consider in the AMOUNT only the *first row* and resets it to `NULL` in the *duplicated* rows.

```
select ID, 
case when row_number() over (partition by id order by second_id) = 1 then AMOUNT end as AMOUNT, 
SECOND_ID, FIRST_ID, AMOUNT2
from first
join second on first.id = second.first_id;

        ID     AMOUNT  SECOND_ID   FIRST_ID    AMOUNT2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10          1          1        100
         1                     2          1        100
         2         20          3          2        100
```

Now you can safely sum in a separate *subquery*

```
with tab as (
select ID, 
case when row_number() over (partition by id order by second_id) = 1 then AMOUNT end as AMOUNT, 
SECOND_ID, FIRST_ID, AMOUNT2
from first
join second on first.id = second.first_id
)
select id, sum(nvl(amount,0) + nvl(amount2,0)) 
from tab
group by id
;

        ID SUM(NVL(AMOUNT,0)+NVL(AMOUNT2,0))
---------- ---------------------------------
         1                               210
         2                               120
```

Note also that this is an answer to *your question*. Some will argue that in your situation **you should first aggregate and than join**. This will also resolve your problem possible more elegantly.